# How to integrate by parts of $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} u(t,x) e^{i\omega x}dx$

Tags: integration

How to solve the following by integration by parts $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} u(t,x) e^{i\omega x}dx$$

In the class, my professor wrote down the following  $$=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u e^{i\omega x}  - i\omega \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(t,x)e^{i\omega x}dx$$

Because of $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} $, I have no idea what $u$, $v$, $du$ and $dv$ are in this case.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you trying to apply the Fourier transform on the heat equation? I think there is a missing minus sign in the power of the exponential function.

Comment: @MachineLearner Yes. But I do not think there is a minus sign there. this is forward FT.

Comment: The definition of the Fourier transform is a mess anyway. The algebra does not change. But normally the Fourier transform has a negative power and the inverse Fourier transform has a positive power (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general formula for integration by parts is given by

$$\int_a^{b}f(x)g(x)~dx = \left[\int f(x)dx~g(x)\right]_a^b-\int_a^b\left[\int f(x)dx\dfrac{dg(x)}{dx} \right]dx.$$

For your problem $f(x) = \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ and $g(x)=\exp(i\omega x)$. This will result in
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} u(t,x) e^{i\omega x}dx=\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(t,x) \exp(i\omega x)\right]_{-\infty}^\infty-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(t,x)\left[ i\omega \exp(i \omega x)\right]~dx$$
$$=\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(t,x) \exp(i\omega x)\right]_{-\infty}^\infty-i\omega\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(t,x)\exp(i \omega x)~dx.$$

You can apply this procedure one again to get an integral of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(t,x)\exp(i\omega x) dx$$.